# How do i do a 301 redirect from a dynamic url with query string to base url?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

I want to redirect this link: **http://www.kuraikaze.com/?awt_l=KN6HU&awt_m=41Jd85ntcrWHhWh** to my site's base url at **http://www.kuraikaze.com**

Any ideas how to go about this? I've tried Rewrite and Redirect but it's not working.

All Help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why you not using google? https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+301+redirect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=vfvQUv31M-OT4AT4tIHwCA. Or if your code is not working, write it  in your question text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)awt_l=KN6HU&awt_m=41Jd85ntcrWHhWh(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [L,R=301]
```

**UPDATE:** To make it dynamic:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)awt_l=[^&]*&awt_m=[^&]*(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [L,R=301]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. It works wonders! How about if the numbers/letters after the = signs are random? How do i do the redirect for that?

Comment: Sure that can be done, see the updated answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use header function.

Check link 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php